# What is php $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']?

Tags: php, http-headers

With php I can see the index "REDIRECT_STATUS" in the $_SERVER array but php.net makes no mention of it.  I have a custom error page that throws a 404 but "REDIRECT_STATUS" is still 200.  So What exactly is the status code referring to?

Comment: [**`This should shed some light`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#105602) (taken from the php.net $_SERVER manual)

Comment: Yeah I saw that but it doesn't really explain much in a way that I can understand.

Comment: These variables come from whatever is running PHP... in your case, probably your web server.  What server are you using?

Comment: As Brad says, this is set by the web server (PHP just makes it available in the `$_SERVER` superglobal) - it's not an HTTP request header. In the case of Apache this should be set to `404` in the case of a custom 404 `ErrorDocument`. However, if it's not Apache then it might not be. [This old bug post](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1828) appears to suggest that lighttpd is setting this to 200 in the case of a 404.

Comment: @w3dk - About a year late responding but it's Apache (v2.4) and no it's not throwing a 404 which is what I'd expect and why I found it so odd.

Comment: `REDIRECT_STATUS` will be set whenever any internal rewrites occur, so whether it is set to 404 or not when the "custom error page" is called could depend on _how_ the custom error page is being called. Is this still a current issue?

Comment: Only in that it's still a bit vague and there aren't really any acceptable answers to the question.  To be honest, your comments (and Darren's link) are the closest thing to something that actually answers the question.. maybe you should consolidate them and post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [php-src code](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=REDIRECT_STATUS) suggests the [documentation link](http://php.net/security.cgi-bin), namely

```
<p>For more information as to <i>why</i> this behaviour exists,
see the <a href=\"http://php.net/security.cgi-bin\">\
manual page for CGI security</a>.</p>\n\
```

to read about CGI security. With the `REDIRECT_STATUS` variable - it is no HTTP Header but a variable that is passed from the web server to the CGI program, in this case the php-cgi or php-fpm process - you tell the php-cgi or php-fpm process that the request has been processed by the web server in a controlled way and not somehow else, by directly accessing these CGI scripts.

Historically you configured the web server to handle CGI binaries in a special directory - something like `$DOCROOT/cgi-bin` - and you made all CGI scripts accessible through some URL `http://SERVERNAME/cgi-bin/`.

Now, if you call a PHP CGI Program through such a (direct) URL `http://SERVERNAME/cgi-bin/php-cgi/PATH_TO_PHP_SCRIPT`, the default behaviour of php-cgi is to process the document `/PATH_TO_PHP_SCRIPT` and thus might bypass the web servers access controls. The `/PATH_TO_PHP_SCRIPT` Document will be processed, though the server might disallow /PATH_TO_PHP_SCRIPT, as the request already left the web server and entered the PHP process. With the help of php, such a server would leak information and you would need another access check layer for all PHP scripts.

To stop this behaviour you can configure the PHP-CGI program to only handle requests that set the `REDIRECT_STATUS` Header, which is impossible for an external client, to set in the direct request. Only the web server - in the middle between client and php - can set this header and the web server suggests a HTTP status - such as 200, 404, 403 or what you like - and allows PHP to process this status. But even the pure existence of this header informs the PHP process, that the request has been processed in a regular way by the web server.

*Opinion: The better way to protect against such a usage would be, to configure the web server to **disallow** direct calls to PHP CGI through a default /cgi-bin/ path.*

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this HTTP header before but, what I can understand about the URL @Darren had posted is that you can point out all your errors (those errors who results in a 4xx or 5xx HTTP header) to **just one php file**. And in that php file you can know which specific error occur by accessing this REDIRECT_STATUS HTTP header.

Comment: `REDIRECT_STATUS` is not an "HTTP header". HTTP request headers are turned into `HTTP_<header>` elements in the `$_SERVER` array. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is set by the server (PHP then does its thing to make this available in the `$_SERVER` superglobal as well). In the case of Apache this is an environment variable that is set whenever there is an internal subrequest (which includes rewrites, but not redirects) and is set to the HTTP status code in the case of an error (an internal subrequest in the case of a custom error document).